# How to exclude the common terms?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have two custom taxonomies Tax1 and Tax2. Suppose in a post Name1 is the term name to both taxonomies. Like this

Tax1 value is Name1
Tax2 values are Name1,Name2,Name3

But I want to exclude the common terms "Name1" from the Tax2 taxonomy.

How can I execute it?

Comment: Exclude in what context? When you're outputting the links? Do you have the code you're currently using?

Comment: Selecting the taxonomy terms while writing the post, I want to show them in the post body.

Comment: I have the generic codes to show them BUT couldn't able to exclude the common terms.